# Getting error as E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: protractor

I'm getting below error while executing this code -

> E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Need your help to resolve this issue in Protractor version 5.4.3

```
let objectLocator = function(){

    var webElement = null;

    //find locator using provided locator type and locator value
    this.findLocator = function (locator, value) {
        var locatorType = locator[0];
        var locatorValue = locator[1];
        if (typeof locatorType !== 'undefined') {
            if (locatorValue.includes('#REPLACE#')) {
                locatorValue = locatorValue.replace('#REPLACE#', value);
            }
            if (locatorType == 'id') {
                if (locatorValue !== 'undefined') {
                    this.webElement = element(by.id(locatorValue));
                }
            } else if (locatorType == 'name') {
                if (locatorValue !== 'undefined') {
                    this.webElement = element(by.name(locatorValue));
                }
            } else if (locatorType == 'xpath') {
                if (locatorValue !== 'undefined') {
                    this.webElement = element(by.xpath(locatorValue));
                }
            } else if (locatorType == 'css') {
                if (locatorValue !== 'undefined') {
                    this.webElement = element(by.css(locatorValue));
                }
            }
        }
        return this.webElement;
    };
};

module.exports = new objectLocator();
```

Comment: what line are you getting that error?

Comment: Hey, I'm getting that error on line -                                                                         
 var locatorType = locator[0];   Could you please help me. I'm stuck badly.

Comment: How you are calling the "objectLocator ". @NiketaBihani

Comment: Try below code
 var locatorType = locator;
 var locatorValue = locator;